# Как читать файлы с ext4 ?

Tags: c#

Подскажите существует ли библиотеки для работы с ext3/ext4,
или как встроить в свою программу какие нибудь механизмы чтобы можно было читать и копировать файлы находящиеся на Linux машине c файловой системой ext3/ext4 .

Comment: А при чем тут C#? Если в ОС есть двайвер, позволяющий читать такую ФС, то и программа сможет (если есть права на чтение)

Comment: В стандартной установке Windows нету, а мне надо чтобы моя прога  на любой машине с Виндой читала файлы с Linux

Comment: [Тыц](https://dogfuntomdev.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/перевод-3-способа-работы-с-разделами-linux/). Придётся ставить драйвер.

Comment: А линукс по отношению к машине с виндой где при этом находится? На соседнем разделе диска?

Comment: В локальной сети